# Graphical Themes for GRUB

Tags: grub2, bootloader, burg

I am a fan of BURG because it makes GRUB look pretty. However, it hasn't been supported in ages and doesn't work properly on UEFI systems. Has anyone out there made something similar recently?

Comment: Although this is not a perfect answer, but I still recommend grub-customizer. It can change many GRUB settings, including the background picture and the fonts. But it is not BURG, no beautiful themes provided.

Answer (score 1):

Try this my friend : Grub customizer. with this tool you can customize your ubuntu grub. Download from here: https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer/+files/grub-customizer_3.0.4-0ubuntu1%7Eppa1p_i386.deb

After install please running it , Go to appearance tab and custom ur background boot as u want it from there.

[image]

[image]